# Not able to open the Stack Overflow website from Nokia 5800

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I'm using my [Nokia 5800](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_5800_XpressMusic) phone to access Stack Overflow. But I'm unable to load it. The site is not opening. Have anyone experienced it? I'm trying this with the Nokia web browser and also with [Opera Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mobile) 10.

I'm able to access other websites like Gmail, Yahoo, Meta Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: What is happening or not happening? Is the entire site timing out? Is it not displaying correctly?

Comment: No repro with a Nokia 5800. The site opens just fine.

Comment: @Pekka: With nokia 5800 default web browser, m getting "Invalid Server Name" which is i think timeout error and in opera mobile 10, m getting "Error 503, DNS Error". BTW, i had added this post from my nokia 5800 - so all other websites are working fine[no networking, internet connectivity issue]. :)

Comment: @justk doesn't Opera Mobile use some kind of proxy, and aren't there known problems between SO and that proxy? If I remember correctly.

Comment: @Pekka do not have any proxy set. Also checked with IP address but no luck.

Comment: @Pekka: That was eventually fixed. I'm using Opera Mini 4 right now.

Answer (score 3):

You can always view a read-only version of the site here:

http://stackmobile.com

It is designed for mobile phones, so it should work no problem.

**Disclaimer:** I made it.

Answer (score 1):

try this search

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22opera%22+proxy